# Implementing server push with Twisted framework

Tags: push-notification, chat, push, twisted, twisted.web

I am developing a group chat using the python Twisted framework. The technique I am using is Long polling with Ajax. I am returning SERVER_NOT_DONE_YET to keep the connection open. The code is non-blocking and allows other requests. How much scalable is it ??

However, I want to move ahead of this streaming over open connections. I want to implement a pure server push. How to do it ? Do I need to go in the direction of XMPP ? If I open a socket on the server for each unique client, which web server would best suit the bridging ? How much scalable would it be ?

I want it to be as much scalable as the C10K problem.I would like to stick to Twisted because it has a lot of protocol implementations in easy steps. Please point me in the right direction. Thanx

Comment: When you ask "how much scalable in it", what form do you expect the answer to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long-polling works, but isn't necessarily your best option. It starts getting really nasty in terms of integration with firewalls and flaky internet connections. For example, at work, a lot of our customers' firewalls kill off any HTTP connection that isn't active for 10-20 seconds.

We've solved a lot of problems by switching over to WebSocket over SSL. WebSocket gives you a full-duplex channel, which is perfect for server push. By using SSL, firewalls are often less aggressive in their garbage collecting, and [transparent proxies are often fooled by the TLS encryption](http://weltam.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/websocket-firewall-and-proxy-oh-my/). You will still need to manage the occasional disconnection on an application-level, even if you're using WebSockets instead of long-polling, but even that can be handled gracefully by having a decent recovery protocol, regardless of whatever transport protocol you use.

This being said, instead of going directly for WebSockets, we've decided to use [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client). The main reason for this choice was that SockJS can use WebSockets when available (rfc6455, hixie-76, hybi-10), but also fall back to xhr-streaming, xdr-streaming, [etc](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client#supported-transports-by-name), if the client's browser does not support it (or if the connection fails). When I say that it can "fall back", I mean that the code you use on the client side remains exactly the same, SockJS takes care of the dirty work.

On the server side, the same is true. We currently use [Cyclone](http://cyclone.io/)'s [SockJS implementation](https://github.com/flaviogrossi/sockjs-cyclone) for Twisted (in production), but we're also aware of [DesertBus'](https://github.com/DesertBus/sockjs-twisted/) implementation, which we still have to check out. There's also some other stuff that we're hoping to check out, for example [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/), and the accompanying [Autobahn|Python](http://autobahn.ws/python/).

With regards to performance, we use [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) for SSL termination and load-balancing. HAProxy's [performance is pretty amazing](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/10g.html), on a multitude of levels.

Answer (score 0):

We have migrated to WebSockets now. It works perfectly fine !!